# Can not get selected value of dropdown in UI tree in angular

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<select
    data-ng-model="completionPercentage"
    class="pull-right" 
    style="margin-right:20px" 
    data-ng-options="c.percentage for c in TaskCompletionPercentage" 
    ng-change="PercentageCompleted()">
  <option value="">0%</option>
</select>`
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.PercentageCompleted = function () {
    alert($scope.completionPercentage);
}
```

Comment: set an value in the option eg: value="1"

Comment: Needs more code to show what's going on around this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pass your `completionPercentage` model in function call and receive it in your controller. It will work too